# I want to save input from html to txt file (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a register site that will take user information and save it to a text file (it needs to be a text file, not a database).

This is my controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Register()
{
    UserRLModel cos = new UserRLModel();
    string root = @"D:\dotNET\RiderProjects\WebApplication3\UserInfo\Users.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(root))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(cos.Name);
    };
    return View(cos.Name);
}
```

This is my model:

```cs
using System;
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class UserRLModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.UserRLModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "UserRL", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Wprowadź dane użytkownika</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-default" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Anuluj", "Index", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue you're facing? Not sure how to accept html input or something else?

Comment: If your aim is saving the file, then it means that at every point your user submits, your file will be overwritten because you have the name of the file hardcoded in the path string adn you are not appending to the existing content